# Merge three tables in Select query by rule 3, 2, 1 records from each table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Merge three tables in a `Select` query by rule 3, 2, 1 records from each table as follows:

- TableA: ID, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC,....
- TableB: ID, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC,....
- TableC: ID, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC,....
- `ID` : auto number in each table
- `FieldA` will be unique in all three tables.

I am looking for a `Select` query to merge three tables as follows:

- TOP three records from `TableA` sorted by ID
- TOP two records from `TableB` sorted by ID
- TOP 1 record from `TableC` sorted by ID

Repeat this until select all records from all three tables.

If some table has fewer records or does not meet the criteria, ignore that and continue with others.

My attempt:

I did it totally through programming way, like cursors and `If` conditions inside a SQL Server stored procedure.

It makes delay.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @iminiki Make one tmp  Table filled with 1000 IDs or total Numbers from three tables, then using SQL cursor, While loop, If Conditions and variables filled tmp table and last use select Query

Comment: is cursor is accepted for your process.

Comment: if Tables contains 7 rows then what should your output?

Comment: TableA, TableA, TableA, TableB, TableB, TableC, TableA, TableA, TableA, TableB, TableC, TableA, TableB, TableB, TableC, TableB, TableB, TableC, TableC, TableC,,,,

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of information to go with here, but I assume you can use UNION to combine multiple statements.

```
SELECT * TableA ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET 3 ROWS 
UNION
SELECT * TableB ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET 2 ROWS 
UNION
SELECT * TableC ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS
```

Execute and see if this works.

/AF

Comment: This question is about (Microsoft) **SQL Server** - and neither SQL Server, nor the ANSI/ISO SQL Standard know a `LIMIT` operator.....

Comment: Thanks for the note! @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

This requires a formula that takes row numbers from each table and transforms it into a series of integers that skips the desired values.

In the query below, I am adding some CTE for the sake of shortening the formula. The real magic is in the `UNION`. Also, I am adding an additional field for your control. Feel free to get rid of it.

```
WITH A_Aux as (
SELECT 'A' As FromTable, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum, TableA.*
FROM TableA
), B_Aux AS (
SELECT 'B' As FromTable, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum, TableB.*
FROM TableB
), C_Aux AS (
SELECT 'C' As FromTable, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY ID) AS RowNum, TableC.*
FROM TableC
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RowNum+3*FLOOR((RowNum-1)/3) As ColumnForOrder, A_Aux.* FROM A_Aux
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3+RowNum+4*FLOOR((RowNum-1)/2), B_Aux.* FROM B_Aux
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6*RowNum, C_Aux.* FROM C_Aux
) T
ORDER BY ColumnForOrder
```

PS: note the pattern `Offset + RowNum + (6-N) * Floor((RowNum-1)/N)` to group N records together (it of course simplifies a lot for `TableC`).

PPS: I don't have a SQL server at hand to test it. Let me know if there is a syntax error.

Comment: This is much better till now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this..

```
    GO

    select * into #temp1 from (select  * from  table1) as t1
    select * into #temp2 from (select  * from  table2) as t2
    select * into #temp3 from (select  * from  table3) as t3

    select * into #final from (select col1, col2, col3 from #temp1 where 1=0) as tb

    declare @i int

    set @i=1
    while( (select COUNT(*) from #temp1)>@i)
    Begin

    ;with ct1 as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as Slno, * from #temp1
    ),ct2 as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as Slno, * from #temp2
    ),ct3 as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as Slno, * from #temp3
    ),cfinal as (
    select top 3 * from #temp1
    union all
    select top 2 * from #temp2
    union  all
    select top 1 * from #temp3
    )
    insert into #final ( col1 , col2, col3 )
    select col1, col2, col3 from cfinal

    delete from #temp1 where id in (select top 3 ID from #temp1)
    delete from #temp2 where id in (select top 2 ID from #temp2)
    delete from #temp3 where id in (select top 1 ID from #temp3)

    set @i = @i+1

    End

    Select * from #final

    Drop table #temp1
    Drop table #temp2
    Drop table #temp3

    GO
```

First create temp table for all 3 tables with each insert delete the inserted record and this will result you the desired result, if nothing is missing from my side.
Please see to this if this works.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I create three temp tables as ta, tb, tc.

```
select * into #ta from (
select 'A' a
union all
select 'A' a
union all
select 'A' a
union all
select 'A' a
union all
select 'A' a
union all
select 'A' a
union all
select 'A' a
) a

select * into #tb from (
select 'B' b
union all
select 'B' 
union all
select 'B' 
union all
select 'B' 
union all
select 'B' 
) b

select * into #tc from (
select 'C' c
union all
select 'C' 
union all
select 'C' 
union all
select 'C' 
union all
select 'C' 
) c
```

If tables match you tables, then the output looks like `A,A,A,B,B,C,A,A,A,B,B,C,A,B,C,C,C`

**T-SQL**

```
declare @TAC int = (select count (*) from #ta)      -- Table A Count = 7
declare @TBC int = (select count (*) from #tb)      -- Table B Count = 5

declare @TAR int = @TAC % 3                         -- Table A Reminder = 1  
declare @TBR int = @TBC % 2                         -- Table B Reminder = 1 

declare @TAQ int = (@TAC - @TAR) / 3                -- Table A Quotient = (7 - 1) / 3 = 2, is will passed on NTILE
                                                    -- So we gonna split as two group (111), (222)
declare @TBQ int = (@TBC - @TBR) / 2                -- Table B Quotient = (5 - 1) / 2 = 2, is will passed on NTILE
                                                    -- So we gonna split as two group (11), (22)

select * from (
 select *, NTILE (@TAQ) over ( order by a) FirstOrder, 1 SecondOrder from (
  select top (@TAC - @TAR) * from #ta order by a
 ) ta                                               -- 6 rows are obtained out of 7.
 union all 
 select *, @TAQ + 1, 1 from (
  select top (@TAR) * from #ta order by a desc
 ) ta                                               -- Remaining one row is obtained. Order by desc is must
                                                    -- Here FirstOrder is next value of previous value. 
 union all

 select *, NTILE (@TBQ) over ( order by b), 2  from (
  select top (@TBC - @TBR) * from #tb order by b
 ) tb                                               
 union all 
 select *, @TBQ + 1, 2 from (
  select top (@TBR) * from #tb order by b desc
 ) tb           

 union all 

 select *, ROW_NUMBER () over (order by c), 3 from #tc                                  
) abc order by FirstOrder, SecondOrder
```

Let me explain the T-SQL:
Before that, FYR: [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [Row Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

1. Get the count.
2. Find the Quotient which will pass to NTILE function.
3. Order by the NTILE value and static.

**Note:**

1. I am using SQL Server 2017.
2. If T-SQL works fine, then you need to change the column in `order by <yourcolumn>`.